# smtpClient doesn't read the Web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, smtpclient

In my MVC4 application, I'm trying to get mail sent using Web.config for configuration settings.
I have papercut running as a mock SMTP server. When I try to use smtpClient and set host="localhost" in my code (that is, not through Web.config) everything works just fine.

My Web.config

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="someone@somewhere.net">
        <network
           host="localhost"
           userName=""
           password=""
           defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

My code

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(myEmailObject);
```

The error

The SMTP host was not specified

Comment: There are multiple web.config's in a WPF application. Did you try putting it into the one in the app's root directory?

Comment: That's soooo true, I'm an a$%^#s editing the Web.config in the Views folder all night, banging my head on the keyboard. Thx!
Can you post that as an actual answer so I can give you the kudos and close my question. (I'm a bit embarrassed you know :)

Comment: Added the answer... don't worry, I have seen several people make the same mistake. You are not alone :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are multiple web.config's in a ASP.NET MVC application. In order for most of the system related settings to take effect, they have to be placed inside the application's root web.config. That means the one that the server sees as "~/web.config" and that is in the root folder of the Visual Studio solution.

Comment: I can't vote up yet, as I do not have enough rep yet (signed up yesterday). I did mark it as the absolutely right answer! Thx, again!